# Ant Java Build Path set by Eclipse is Missing a Library at Compile Time

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I'm using eclipse and ant to compile a java project. The ant compile script calls `javac` using a classpath refid of `classpath`, which is set based on System Property variable `java.build.path`.

My `java.build.path` variable is missing a library that was specified in

> Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries.

That is, the external jar was properly added to the list of libraries to add to the build path, is not missing or corrupt, and I have every expectation that eclipse would include the library in the build path. My build fails because `java.build.path` is missing this library.

Furthermore, the file `<projectDir>/.classpath` contains a valid `classpathentry` element for the missing jar file.

When building, `javac` fails at an import statement, claiming that the package does not exist. The value of `java.build.classpath` contains many of the libraries I set in the project properties, but does not include the missing library. Its as if the project property for that external jar was never set.

For what its worth, the missing library is `jboss/lib/jbosssx.jar`

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where my configuration was messed up.

Using `External Tools Configurations` within eclipse, I found another `Classpath` settings tab for my ant build that did not contain my library.

Adding my library here caused the build to succeed!

Skywalker, thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

At first,

1. Download `jbosssx.jar` jar file from this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jbosssx/jbosssx.jar.zip)
2. Then keep the jar file in the folder `jboss/lib`

Hope it will solve your issue.

### UPDATE:

Sometimes jar files need to keep in `lib` folder physically. For this reason, you can put the jar file in your project `lib` folder.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want me to copy the library from its location into my project. I don't want to do that. I want the library to live where libraries live, and I want eclipse to set `java.build.path` completely and correctly so that the library is included at compile time.